# Clone Dashboard with Reports

Tags: reporting, dashboard, clone

I have to clone a dashboard for multiple markets (say I have to clone a dashboard aimed at France for every country in Europe). This dashboard has about 10 underlying reports with the same filter (i.e. Market equals France).

Currently, I'm manually opening every report, editing it and using "Save As" to save it. When I'm done with cloning the reports, I clone the dashboard and change all sources. This is quite time consuming.

**Question:** I'm wondering whether it's possible to clone dashboards and their underlying reports in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Force.com Migration tool. You can retrieve reports and dashboards and re-deploy them in your target organisation.

**UPDATE**

Filters in the XML of a report retrieved from Salesforce using the migration tool

```
<filter>
        <criteriaItems>
            <column>LiveChatTranscript.LiveChatTranscriptEvents$Type</column>
            <operator>equals</operator>
            <value>10,12</value>
        </criteriaItems>
</filter>
```